# stuck on a key feature of a tkinter canvas game

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

here is my code I need help with the key feature off position recognition
basically the main mechanic of the game that tells you when your movable
character (man) is on a one of the bad characters (bad);
my problem is how do I do the if statement that tells me: 
  if man is on bad

here is my code that lets the man move around and generates bad

P.S don't spoon feed:

```
from tkinter import *

import random


def up(event):
    c.move(man, 0, -150)
def down(event):
    c.move(man, 0, 150)
def right(event):
    c.move(man, 150, 0)
def left(event):
    c.move(man, -150, 0)

wd = Tk()
wd.bind('<Up>', up)
wd.bind('<Down>', down)
wd.bind('<Right>', right)
wd.bind('<Left>', left)

c = Canvas(wd, height=475, width=450, bg='white', cursor='plus')#room at bottom
c.pack()

plc = random.randint(1,9)
if plc == 1:
    bad = c.create_oval(50,50,100,100,fill='blue')
if plc == 2:
    bad = c.create_oval(200,50,250,100,fill='blue')
if plc == 3:
    bad = c.create_oval(350,50,400,100,fill='blue')
if plc == 4:
    bad = c.create_oval(50,200,100,250,fill='blue')
if plc == 5:
    bad = c.create_oval(200,200,250,250,fill='blue')
if plc == 6:
    bad = c.create_oval(350,200,400,250,fill='blue')
if plc == 7:
    bad = c.create_oval(50,350,100,400,fill='blue')
if plc == 8:
    bad = c.create_oval(200,350,250,400,fill='blue')
if plc == 9:
    bad = c.create_oval(350,350,400,400,fill='blue')

sq1 = c.create_rectangle(0,0,150,150,fill='white')
sq2 = c.create_rectangle(0,150,150,300,fill='white')
sq3 = c.create_rectangle(0,300,150,450,fill='white')
sq4 = c.create_rectangle(150,0,300,150,fill='white')
sq5 = c.create_rectangle(150,150,300,300,fill='white')
sq6 = c.create_rectangle(150,300,300,450,fill='white')
sq7 = c.create_rectangle(300,0,450,150,fill='white')
sq8 = c.create_rectangle(300,150,450,300,fill='white')
sq9 = c.create_rectangle(300,300,450,450,fill='white')

man = c.create_oval(175,175,275,275,fill='red')#25 in each way

catch()

wd.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Click the link in my above comment and read that page about how to properly ask questions on Stack Overflow.  The main thing to remember is you should try to ask a question that uses the least amount of code but gives the same result. Once again read the page I linked to for asking help.

Answer (score 1):

from [Methods on Canvas Widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) you can use `.bbox` in combination with `.find_enclosed` to check if two objects are intersecting:

```
def is_intercecting(canvas,tag1,tag2):
    return tag1 in canvas.find_enclosed(*canvas.bbox(tag2))
```

or for your case specifically:

```
def is_man_touching_bad():
    return bad in c.find_enclosed(*c.bbox(man))
```

then every time you call one of the movement functions you could use this to check if they are colliding.

(I'm guessing this would be used in the `catch` function which you call but don't define in your provided code)

EDIT: by request here is example use of `is_man_touching_bad` this will turn the `man` black when moved over `bad`:

```
def catch():
    if is_man_touching_bad():
        c.itemconfigure(man,fill="black")
    else:
        c.itemconfigure(man,fill="red")
```

be sure to call this every time the position is updated:

```
def up(event):
    c.move(man, 0, -150)
    catch()
def down(event):
    c.move(man, 0, 150)
    catch()
def right(event):
    c.move(man, 150, 0)
    catch()
def left(event):
    c.move(man, -150, 0)
    catch()
```

Comment: im sorry can u expand how i check if man is colliding with bad by printing (man is intersecting bad)  plz

Comment: is that a sufficient example use? I put it in a function but you could just as easily put `bad in c.find_enclosed(*c.bbox(man))` in the appropriate conditional statement

Comment: If you accept the answer provided be sure to label it appropriately ;)